# Discord.py Delete Message on permission Error

Tags: python, discord.py

Im about to write Two separate help commands for my Discord Bot. Ohne that should show up when the user has kick permissions and the other if the user doesnt. My code looks like this:

```
@commands.command(aliases=['Help'])
@has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def help(self, ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    print("you have permissions")

@help.error
async def Help(self, error, ctx):

    await ctx.message.delete()
    print("you have no permissions")
```

But when someone without permissions try to run the command, the console raises this Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'MissingPermissions' object has no attribute 'message'
```

My Question now is: How can I Delete the Message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example in the discord.py docs: [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)

> The first parameter of the error handler is the [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) while the second one is an exception that is derived from [CommandError](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CommandError). A list of errors is found in the [Exceptions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#ext-commands-api-errors) page of the documentation.
>
> ```py
> @bot.command()
> async def info(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
>     """Tells you some info about the member."""
>     fmt = '{0} joined on {0.joined_at} and has {1} roles.'
>     await ctx.send(fmt.format(member, len(member.roles)))
>
> @info.error
> async def info_error(ctx, error):
>     if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
>         await ctx.send('I could not find that member...')
> ```

As you can see, `ctx` is the first argument

So just change that `async def Help(self, error, ctx):` to `async def Help(self, ctx, error):`

---

But also you should rename your error function to `help_error` instead of `Help`;)